# Mickey Mouse toy bin file analysis

Tags: binary-analysis, ghidra, radare2, binwalk

I am trying to reverse engineer a Mickey Mouse toy just for fun but I am stuck.
The toy has several buttons that play various phrases and songs.
My aim was to see if I can read those songs from the eeprom as the other chip is encased in resin.
I was able to read the 2mb bin file and I have tried various softwares for reverse engineering but I didn't find very useful information.

binwalk -A mickey.bin:

```
    DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1581594       0x18221A        ARMEB instructions, function prologue
```

In imHex I was only able to identify this at the start of the file:

```
Date: 2009-11-09Version:     V06Author:    A\xAAUi\x96/\x00\xD0\xFF8#
```

In Ghidra I was only able to find this:

```
                             //
                         // ram 
                         // ram:00000000-ram:001fffff
                         //
                         **************************************************************
                         *                          FUNCTION                          *
                         **************************************************************
                         undefined Reset()
         undefined         r0:1           <RETURN>
                         Reset                                           XREF[1]:     Entry Point(*)  
    00000000 44 61 74 65     ldrbvs     r6,[r4,#-0x144]!
                         **************************************************************
                         *                          FUNCTION                          *
                         **************************************************************
                         undefined UndefinedInstruction()
         undefined         r0:1           <RETURN>
                         UndefinedInstruction                            XREF[1]:     Entry Point(*)  
    00000004 3a 20 32 30     eorccs     r2,r2,r10, lsr r0
                         SupervisorCall                                  XREF[1]:     Entry Point(*)  
    00000008 30              ??         30h    0
    00000009 39              ??         39h    9
    0000000a 2d              ??         2Dh    -
    0000000b 31              ??         31h    1
                         **************************************************************
                         *                          FUNCTION                          *
                         **************************************************************
                         undefined PrefetchAbort()
         undefined         r0:1           <RETURN>
                         PrefetchAbort                                   XREF[1]:     Entry Point(*)  
    0000000c 31 2d 30 39     ldmdbcc    r0!,{r0,r4,r5,r8,r10,r11,sp}
                         DataAbort                                       XREF[1]:     Entry Point(*)  
    00000010 56              ??         56h    V
    00000011 65              ??         65h    e
    00000012 72              ??         72h    r
    00000013 73              ??         73h    s
    00000014 69              ??         69h    i
    00000015 6f              ??         6Fh    o
    00000016 6e              ??         6Eh    n
    00000017 3a              ??         3Ah    :
                         **************************************************************
                         *                          FUNCTION                          *
                         **************************************************************
                         undefined IRQ()
         undefined         r0:1           <RETURN>
                         IRQ                                             XREF[1]:     Entry Point(*)  
    00000018 20 20 20 20     eorcs      r2,r0,r0, lsr #32
                         **************************************************************
                         *                          FUNCTION                          *
                         **************************************************************
                         undefined FIQ()
         undefined         r0:1           <RETURN>
                         FIQ                                             XREF[1]:     Entry Point(*)  
    0000001c 20 56 30 36     ldrtcc     r5,[r0],-r0,lsr #0xc
    00000020 41 75 74 68     ldmdavs    r4!,{r0,r6,r8,r10,r12,sp,lr}^
    00000024 6f 72 3a 20     eorcss     r7,r10,pc, ror #0x4
    00000028 20              ??         20h
```

Since I am a beginer I might have not used the reverse engineering software properly.

Here is the bin file:
https://easyupload.io/3yyq4x

Comment: What is the toy? What are the other chips on the toy? (If there is another chip for storage how do you know the EEPROM contains the songs?)

Comment: You're trying to disassemble ASCII, look at the values, that's the version string.  look for other bytes

Comment: @secfren The toy looks something similar to this [link](https://http2.mlstatic.com/D_NQ_NP_765489-MPE32063706571_092019-O.jpg)
Apart from the eeprom there are just some passive componets and a a chip enclosed in a black blob.
I was assuming the songs are in the eeprom since they are in Romanian, that implies that the toys were built in multiple languages. I supposed that the manufacturer used the eeprom for the songs but I'm not sure

Comment: @mumbel what other bytes do you suggest?

Comment: Inside? PCB? Model? What about the other chips?

Comment: Looks like data for me. there are sections with  00 6d db b6 and some more pattern between more varying sections. Assuming that each one of those varying sections is a audio clip. thats what i was able to spot from a quick check on the file.

Comment: Byte structure between 0x6C and 0x127 looks like some sort of index. 2 bytes that are always incrementing, a zero byte and a byte that changes between each "record". before that there is some weird "padding" and a single byte that doesnt seem to match up to anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the file disassembled into the audio segments. Format is pretty simple.

(for further analysis the separated files: https://nplusc.de/mickey.bin-splitted.zip )

File has a index list at 0x6c of 0x29 uint32 offsets, at each offset there is a length field (uint32) and then the raw file.

File format as a 010editor binary template:

```c
byte randomgarbage[0x6b];
local uint64 returnoffset = FTell();
uint32 sizes[0x29];

struct FILE{
    uint32 file_size;
    byte content[file_size];
};

FSeek(returnoffset);
local uint i = 0;
for(i = 0; i<0x29;i++)
{
    FSeek(sizes[i]);
    FILE file;
}
```

Used this java program to split the file:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class MickeyBinSplitter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(args[0],"r")) {
            File out = new File(args[0]+"out");
            out.mkdirs();
            file.seek(0x6b);
                            //guessed from file reading
            for(int i=0; i < 0x29;i++)
            {
                byte[] swapMe = new byte[4];
                file.read(swapMe);
                ByteBuffer wrapped = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[]{swapMe[3],swapMe[2],swapMe[1],swapMe[0]}); // big-endian by default
                int offsetFile = wrapped.getInt();
                System.out.println(offsetFile);
                long retval = file.getFilePointer();

                file.seek(offsetFile);

                file.read(swapMe);
                wrapped = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[]{swapMe[3],swapMe[2],swapMe[1],swapMe[0]}); // big-endian by default
                int lenFile = wrapped.getInt();
                System.out.println(lenFile);
                byte[] innerFile = new byte[lenFile];
                file.read(innerFile);
                file.seek(retval);
                try (RandomAccessFile outRandom = new RandomAccessFile(new File(out, i + ".bin"), "rw")) {
                    outRandom.write(innerFile);
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Excelent find! I am trying to do the same in imHex for learning purposes. What was your thought process on doing this? What was the first thing you searched?

Comment: scrolling over the file. i got a slightly different wired brain and scrolling over a file often shows me patterns. knowing that it looked like a data flash and not a code flash (and a few similar formats that i twiddled apart) got me to look for stuff that looks like a index/offset table (those often show as a series of increasing values). rest was cross-referencing and guessworks. java program was quickly cobbled together after i had the binary template done (those are useful for quick verify if a guess fits). Nasty traps are when the tables are not really aligned. was off by one byte

Comment: first and that caused me to look at wrong values. the zero bytes in the table pointed me to the offset then